# android sms null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, sms

Iam getting a null pointer exception while sending some string text as an sms to other emulator.I have a button which on clicking will send the text present in the textView as an sms to other emulator.

Here is the code of textview and button class

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.ticketprocess);




         SecureMessagesActivity sma = new SecureMessagesActivity();

         message = sma.getMessageBody();
         tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
           tv.setText(message); 



         submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
         submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

    SendSms sms = new SendSms();
    sms.sendSMS("15555215556", message);

}});

  }
```

and here is the code of sendsms class

```
public class SendSms extends Activity {

    public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {        
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        //---when the SMS has been sent---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;                        
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);        
    }

}
```

now on clicking the button the device gets force close message, the error in logcat is

```
06-14 17:47:47.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8403): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 17:47:47.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8403): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 17:47:47.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8403):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:120)
06-14 17:47:47.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8403):     at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:226)
06-14 17:47:47.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8403):     at com.mypackage.ULWAFMS1.SendSms.sendSMS(SendSms.java:38)
06-14 17:47:47.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8403):     at com.mypackage.ULWAFMS1.page1$1.onClick(page1.java:43)
06-14 17:47:47.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8403):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
06-14 17:47:47.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8403):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
06-14 17:47:47.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8403):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-14 17:47:47.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8403):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-14 17:47:47.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8403):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-14 17:47:47.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8403):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-14 17:47:47.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8403):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 17:47:47.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8403):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-14 17:47:47.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8403):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-14 17:47:47.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8403):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-14 17:47:47.249: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8403):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you ask permission in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Check id's of both textView and button... make sure they don't return null..

Comment: yes indeed, i forgot to add send permission in manifest file. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is occurring where you are creating your `PendingIntent` objects at the start of your `sendSms` method. You are implementing SendSMS as an activity, but I don't think that it needs to be, and it is not being correctly initialised as an Activity, so you are seeing this failure.

Take out the `extends Activity` from your sendsms class, and change your sendSms method to start as follows:

```
public class SendSms {

    public void sendSMS(Context context, String phoneNumber, String message)
    {        
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
```

Now you'll need to call it as `sendSms( this, "15555215556", message );` from your `onClickListener`;